# Forging SSL certificate to the browser

Tags: tls, certificates, man-in-the-middle

A man in the middle attacker can intercept and send a different certificate (a self-signed one, maybe) to the browser. In this case, browser will show warning to the user and doesn't display's the green pad lock near the URL.

If a single user bypasses the warning, will he still be prone to a man in the middle attack?

How can this issue be overcome? Is it solely left to the end user?

Comment: There are similar questions here but it is not clear if yours is a duplicate since it is too unspecific. If you ask *"How to overcome this issue?"* - do you mean from the perspective of the server the user is accessing, the admin managing the users machine, the admins responsible for the IT security in the network or whoever? If you ask from the perspective of the end user itself the answer would be to  simply not click through the warning.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, I'm asking it in the perspective of enduser. How would 100% of the users know not to proceed. There will be always some set of users proceed to the site (though unsafe). My question is, why is such a security measure is delegated to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can't patch an end user

If a user dismisses all warnings given by the browser, and clicks through, they will be vulnerable to MitM. You simply can't patch the end user.

The reason browsers don't outright remove the ability to click through the warnings is that there are many servers out there, that produce certificate errors because of misconfigurations (or the server admin insists on using self-signed certs). In other cases, it might not be possible for the webserver to be using anything other than a self-signed certificate (for example, if your router/printer wanted to use HTTPS on it's web interface, it wouldn't be possible for it to obtain a CA signed certificate). Completely preventing click through would make these sites inaccessible.

##### [HSTS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) may prevent clickthrough for some users

The primary purpose of HSTS is to tell the browser that it should *always* access the site over HTTPS, which is useful for preventing sslstrip attacks. The HSTS RFC also provides [a non-normative recommendation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6797#section-12.1) to user-agent implementers to provide no recourse to users when a certificate error is encountered on site using HSTS. In other words, the user will not be allowed to click through*.

However, since this just a recommendation, and not a requirement, not all browsers implement this. For example, Chrome on Windows 10 does, while Firefox does not.

<sup>*Of course you can go into the browser's configuration settings and disable HSTS altogether, which will allow you to bypass this protection as well. But normal users are unlikely to be aware of this, so they *probably* won't be able to shoot themselves in the foot.</sup>